# jQuery, clicking "Remove" is making all items disappear but on refresh the items are back and only the removed one is gone

Tags: jquery

I kind of understand why this is happening but I don't understand how to fix it.

HTML Markup:

```
<tr>
    <th>Attachment</th>
    <td>
        <ul>{% for attachment in lineup.attachments %} {% if lineup.obsolete %}
            <li>{{ attachment.name}}</li>{% else %}
            <!-- this will show just the last file -->{# set attachment = lineup.attachments|last #}
            <li><a href='http://files.example.com/{{ attachment.file_url }}' id='{{ attachment.id }}'>{{ attachment.name }}</a>
                <!-- remove attachment link -->{% if perm.remove_files %}
                <input type='hidden' class='id' value='{{ attachment.id }}' /><a class='remove_file' href='javascript:void(0)' style="margin-left: 20px;">Remove</a>{% endif %}</li>{% endif %} {% endfor %}</ul>
    </td>
</tr>
```

jQuery delete:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.remove_file').click(function(){
        $this = $(this);
        $id = $this.parent().find('.id').val();
        if(confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this file?')){
            $.get('phplib/remove_lineup_attachment.php',{ id: $id }, function(){
                $this.parent().parent().remove();
            });
        }
    });
});
```

So it's deleting the right attachment from the database that I want it to delete. The issue is that if I have 5 attachments showing, when I click delete on attachment `#5`, they all disappear and then when I refresh the page they're all back except for `#5` which was the one I deleted.

What my attachment section looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Je4B6.png

Comment: Would `$this.parent().remove();` instead of `$this.parent().parent().remove();` work for you? It's hard to tell based on the HTML you provided. Please post the rendered HTML.

Comment: @j08691 Wow that worked! Right under my nose haha, thanks for the quick suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want to remove the `<li>`, rather than the `<ul>` (which is what you're currently targeting using `.parent().parent()`), the following should work for you:

```
$this.parent().remove();
```